# why res/values/styles.xml dose'nt exist?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-styles, android-sdk-manager

When I make a android app project in AndroidManifest.xml error ecure in `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.azzzz"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I think this error happen because `styles.xml` dose not exist in res/values. 
how I can fix it?

Comment: if its not there then create one.. with name "AppTheme" ..in style.xml

Comment: That is styles.xml with an extra 's'. Can you list the files within res/values. Maybe your styles.xml has a reference to another file `style.xml' and thats causing the error. Just check the contents of /res/values folder

Comment: The name of xml file could be anything you want. What you have to follow is xml tags name in xml file.

Answer (score 0):

i find it!
the `ADT(android development tools)` and `sdk` tools does not match.
all my problem solved by change and match them